# Help: Can't Add App to Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When attempting to add an app to a host named site collection, I get the following error:

> Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them
>   to enable apps

the message displayed when attempting to add a sharepoint store app.

apps are turned on for the web application, so I don't understand why I am getting this error. I can't turn on what is already turned on.

I can acquire apps through central administration, which is on the same web application.

does anyone know how to enable apps for a site collection?

sharepoint 2013 sp1 enterprise, windows server 2012 r2, sql server 2012, farm

Comment: Can you check log and see any errors something like `The site subscription name must exist to complete this operation`

Answer (score 2):

Try this powershell script:

```
# Ensure that the spadmin and sptimer services are running  
Write-Host  
Write-Host "Ensure that the spadmin and sptimer services are running" -ForegroundColor     Yellow  
net start spadminv4  
net start sptimerv4  

# Create your isolated app domain by running the SharePoint Management Shell as an     administrator and typing the following command.  
Write-Host  
Write-Host "Create your isolated app domain by running the SharePoint Management Shell   as an administrator and typing the following command." -ForegroundColor Yellow  
$appdomain = Read-Host "Your App Domain Name"  
Set-SPAppDomain $appdomain  

# Ensure that the SPSubscriptionSettingsService and AppManagementServiceInstance    services are running   
Write-Host  
Write-Host "Ensure that the SPSubscriptionSettingsService and    AppManagementServiceInstance services are running." -ForegroundColor Yellow  
Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or    $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"} | Start-SPServiceInstance  

# Verify that the SPSubscriptionSettingsService and AppManagementServiceInstance services are running   
Write-Host  
Write-Host "Verify that the SPSubscriptionSettingsService and  AppManagementServiceInstance services are running." -ForegroundColor Yellow  
Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or    $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"}  

# Specify an account, application pool, and database settings for the     SPSubscriptionService and AppManagementServiceInstance services   
Write-Host  
Write-Host "Specify an account, application pool, and database settings for the   SPSubscriptionService and AppManagementServiceInstance services." -ForegroundColor Yellow  
$login = Read-Host "The login of a managed account"  
$account = Get-SPManagedAccount $login   
$appPoolSubSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SettingsServiceAppPool -Account     $account  
Write-Host "SettingsServiceAppPool created (1/6)" -ForegroundColor Green  
$appPoolAppSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name AppServiceAppPool -Account    $account  
Write-Host "AppServiceAppPool created  (2/6)" -ForegroundColor Green  
$appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication –ApplicationPool    $appPoolSubSvc –Name SettingsServiceApp –DatabaseName SettingsServiceDB   
Write-Host "SubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication created  (3/6)" -ForegroundColor   Green  
$proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy –ServiceApplication     $appSubSvc  
Write-Host "SubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy created  (4/6)" -  ForegroundColor Green  
$appAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPoolAppSvc -  Name AppServiceApp -DatabaseName AppServiceDB  
Write-Host "AppManagementServiceApplication created  (5/6)" -ForegroundColor Green  
$proxyAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication   $appAppSvc  
Write-Host "AppManagementServiceApplicationProxy created  (6/6)" -ForegroundColor Green  

# Specify your tenant name   
write-host  
Write-Host "Set AppSiteSubscriptionName to 'app'" -ForegroundColor Yellow  
Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "app" -Confirm:$false  
Write-Host "AppSiteSubscriptionName set" -ForegroundColor Green  

# Disable the loopbackcheck in the registry  (optional) usually only done in DEV
Write-Host "Disable the loopbackcheck in the registry" -ForegroundColor Yellow  
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\" -Name   "DisableLoopbackCheck" -PropertyType DWord -Value 1 

Write-Host "Completed"
```

Comment: Disable the loopbackcheck? Really?

Comment: really.. To ensure all the calls initiated from the server itself do not result into any HTTP 401 errors in IIS logs as suggested by MS. thx for the down vote tho :)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: No offense in the downvote, but Microsoft put the security feature there for a reason. http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx

Comment: Usually something I do in dev environments, commented the script

Comment: i agree that the disable loopbackcheck should not have been altered. I clearly had other troubles with my site. I opened a ticket with Microsoft which resulted in rebuilding the app store environment, but in looking back at it, I think my problems were due to 2 specific problems. somehow the app domain url was missing - don't ask - I know I set it, but then when I checked again it was missing. setting it resolved part of the problem. the other part was misconfigured dns. those 2 corrections enabled apps for the site collection.